# PowerShell Normalize List of Names

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some really messed up names from a system that I'm trying to match First and Last names in AD. Just need to parse the strings. I have names such as :

- Hagstrom, N.P., Ana (Analise)
- Banas, R.N., Cynthia
- Saltzmann, N.P., April
- Lee, Christopher
- Rajaram, Pharm.D., Sharmee
- Goode Jr, John (Jack) L
- Reyes, R.N., Meghan
- Miller, M.S., Adrienne M
- Chavez, Gabriela
- Stevens, MS, CCC-SLP, Christopher
- Lockwood Flores, R.N., Jessica

I have tried this, but for some reason, the GivenName isn't being returned properly.

```
$Name = "Saltzmann, N.P., April"

    $GivenName = $Name.Split(",")[$Name.Split(",").GetUpperBound(0)]
    $SN = $Name.Split(",")[0]

    If ($SN.IndexOf("-") -gt -1) { 
     $HypenLast = $SN.Split("-")[0]
     $SNName = $SN.Split("-")[1]
        }

        If ($GivenName.IndexOf(" ") -gt -1) {
     $GivenName = $GivenName.Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Split(" ")[0]
     $MiddleName =$GivenName.Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Split(" ")[1]
        }
```

Trying to take everything before the first comma and everything after last comma, but take letters before the second space of the first name. 
Trying to get LastName FirstName but then need to flip it to FirstName LastName. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for scripts ... It is a place to have tips and advices in coding and scripts that you provide. You should try doing it yourself first.

Comment: Without just giving you code try the following. 1) use the .Split(',') method on the string object to break your string into an array. 2) Use those array strings and use the .Trim() method to remove junk spaces 3) Use the $var[index] to build out the format you need.

Comment: This is where RegEx flexes its muscles and laughs at your text parsing issues as trivial. Useful links: [RegEx General Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and [Popular RegEx Testing Site](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

All of the names could be piped to a script block that uses a regex with some named capture groups.  The named capture group values can be extracted to rebuild the name you need using string interpolation.

```
$nameList | ForEach-Object {
    $match = [Text.RegularExpression.Regex]::Match($_, "(?<last>[\w\s]+),(?:.*,)?(?:\s*)(?<first>\w+)")
    $lastName = $match.Groups["last"].Value
    $firstName = $match.Groups["first"].Value
    "$firstName $lastName"
}
```